# Something's missing

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, story, steganography, crossword-clues

I recently received an e-mail from my cousin who knows I am into puzzles. The body of the puzzles was weird and only thing I know is that he talked about being excited about something the last time I talked with him.

> My God, Sid. You have gotten a an n me. You seem to know so much about puzzles.
>
> I eally am inpired by wha you have earnt so far and really hope to learn much more than you.
>
> So, coming to the point, you do recll me being excite. There was a reason for that and don't worr, I wouldn't tell you.
>
> See, there is no fun in directly telling you. You need to expnd the realms of your brai and o it yourself i.e. find out what I am doing.
>
> I am being harh. But, Hy! It is fun nd I don't think you would complain much,being a ovial guy.
>
> Name f what's next for me is what yo will get. How? That's the fun pat. You eed to find out.
>
> "Give me a hint", you say? My rply is that you only need to stud this e-mail. Have a great day.

SO, what do you think? What's my cousin doing, that is making him so excited?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Your friend is**

> **Missing First Lady and Sea Journey.** Probably he is single on Valentines Day :) which OP confirms is a red herring. Further solving gives **Maiden Voyage** using crossword clues. So probably, your friend is excited about his Cruise Travel.

**Explanations**

> The first letter say **MISSING** which means we need to find the missing letters in the paragraph

**Going ahead**

> My God, Sid. You have gotten a **F**an **I**n me. You seem to know so much about puzzles.
>  
>  I **R**eally am in**S**pired by wha**T** you have **L**earnt so far and really hope to learn much more than you.
>  
>  So, coming to the point, you do rec**A**ll me being excite**D**. There was a reason for that and don't worr**Y**, I wouldn't tell you. 
>  
>  See, there is no fun in directly telling you. You need to exp**A**nd the realms of your brai**N** and **D**o it yourself i.e. find out what I am doing.
>  
>  I am being har**S**h. But, H**E**y! It is fun **A**nd I don't think you would complain much,being a **J**ovial guy.
>  
>  Name **O**f what's next for me is what yo**U** will get. How? That's the fun pa**R**t. You **N**eed to find out.
>  
>  "Give me a hint", you say? My r**E**ply is that you only need to stud**Y** this e-mail. Have a great day.
>
>
>  Which is **MISSING** **FIRST LADY** **AND SEA JOURNEY**
>
>
>  The Cross Word clue tag specifies the next step -
>  (as someone already commented) it is Maiden Voyage.
>  First Lady - **Maiden**
>  Sea Journey- **Voyage**

Comment: You're missing the D on "excite". It makes the word LADY, not LAY.

Comment: @Silenus Yeah. Missed a couple during the edits. Thanks :)

Comment: Excitedly, I called my cousin to inform him of your findings. He just gave a smirk and replied, "Looks like I have a bright future as a puzzler. Congrats. You just found the Red-Herring that I had planted. Now buckle up and solve the puzzle for real, if you want to know."

Comment: @Sid Is it a red herring which needs to be completely ignored or its a clue for next step?

Comment: I called my cousin to enquire about it. He said that this will guide you to the final step and he said. "I forgot to tell you about the tag..." and then the signal became too poor for me to understand anything.

Comment: @Sid Are there any clues? Or a guess work? I have updated something but not sure in what context should I try to solve it.

Answer (score 7):

Some important observations:

> The initial letters of each line make **MISSING**. Indeed, some of the letters are missing in the email and we need to find them.

Tracing the missing letters out:

> My God, Sid. You have gotten a **f**an **i**n me. I **r**eally am in**s**pired by wha**t** you have **l**earnt so far and really hope to learn much more than you. So, coming to the point, you do rec**a**ll me being excite**d**. There was a reason for that and don't worr**y**, I wouldn't tell you. See, there is no fun in directly telling you. You need to exp**a**nd the realms of your brai**n** and **d**o it yourself i.e. find out what I am doing. I am being har**s**h. But, H**e**y! It is fun **a**nd I don't think you would complain much, being a **j**ovial guy. Name **o**f what's next for me is what yo**u** will get. How? That's the fun pa**r**t. You **n**eed to find out. "Give me a hint", you say? My r**e**ply is that you only need to stud**y** this e-mail. Have a great day.

Grouping them gives us:

> **FIRST LADY AND SEA JOURNEY**

Making sense out of this peculiar phrase:

> First lady = **Maiden**, Sea Journey = **Voyage**

Which means, your friend is excited about

> going on the maiden voyage of a cruise ship.

Comment: Excitedly, I called my cousin to inform him of your findings. He just gave a smirk and replied, "Looks like I have a bright future as a puzzler. Congrats. You just found the Red-Herring that I had planted. Now buckle up and solve the puzzle for real, if you want to know."

Comment: I could be mistaken, but I believe "First Lady and Sea Journey" might actually mean "Maiden Voyage".